# Android - Using pageradapter i want to make the FIRST image show 1/4 of the screen and then let it scroll over naturally

Tags: android, image-gallery, android-pageradapter

My goal is to create this.

https://i.imgur.com/73fvHaF.gif

The main problem is that i cant get the image at the first position to stay at 1/4 (or any size) when i scroll that image it will take up the full width of the screen and then act as a normal pageradapter.

I have tried the following

- Objectanimator.ofFloat
- Play around with margin, padding etc
- Find any way to set boundary for the first image
- Set empty imageview in order to push the view to the side, this seems most viable though i have to call notifyDataSetChanged();

When i change data within the adapter, i call notifyDataSetChanged(); which we all know updates the view without any smooth transition.

It feels like this should have a easy and clean solution to it, as long as i know how to set a boundary for the first image. Perhaps im wrong

Here's the code i am using
I have created a custom Gallery widget

---

```
public class ImageGalleryViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public ImageGalleryViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public ImageGalleryViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling
    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new ImageGalleryViewPager.MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
        setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount());
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

I use this in a Cardview

```
    <com.apirix.inspection.views.viewpagers.ImageGalleryViewPager
        android:id="@+id/image_gallery_vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Pageradapter

```
public AssignmentListGalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Media> medias, ViewPager horizontalView) {
    mContext = context;
    mMedias = medias;
    mHorizontalView = horizontalView;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image_gallery_viewpager, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mItemView);


    mUri = mMedias.get(position).getUrl();
    closeAllImagesButton.add(mCloseButton);
    mContainer = container;

    container.setClipToPadding(false);
    container.setPadding(30, 0, 60, 0);

    if (!mUri.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(mUri)
                .fit()
                .into(mFullScreenImageView);
    }

    mCloseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    container.addView(mItemView);
    return mItemView;

}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with a padding inside your cardView but only for the first element of your adapter.

So you will have two card Views:

**row_image_gallery_viewpager_first.xml**

```
    <com.apirix.inspection.views.viewpagers.ImageGalleryViewPager
    android:id="@+id/image_gallery_vp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingEnd="100dp"/>
```

and

**row_image_gallery_viewpager.xml**

```
<com.apirix.inspection.views.viewpagers.ImageGalleryViewPager
        android:id="@+id/image_gallery_vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></RelativeLayout>
```

Then you will have to specify in your adapter wich xml use for the first element:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (position == 0){
                mItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image_gallery_viewpager_first, container, false);
            } else {
                mItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image_gallery_viewpager, container, false);
            }
            ButterKnife.bind(this, mItemView);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Awesome! Now when i swipe the first time, i want the image to fit the pageradapter, take a look at the supplied Gif again https://i.imgur.com/73fvHaF.gif

Comment: Mhh you mean that your second item do not fit the screen?

Comment: On the initial swipe the pageradapter should expand the first image to the containers full width . So i swipe left once, the image expands, i swipe left again i get image number two. Small 1 -> Large 1 -> Image 2 Hope im making myself clear.

Comment: Yeah i see now, that much more complicated but possible.

Comment: Actually i think you need to catch first swipe via a touchlistener with swipe gesture detector. apply a resize animation on the card view to make it expand on the full size. then let the nexts swipe behave normally with adapter. I don't know if i'm clear?

Comment: Yes perfectly clear, i will give this a try and inform you of the result.